# Are Black Holes set to take over the Harmonic Oscillator in the 21st century?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, harmonic-oscillator, black-hole-firewall

A few years ago I attended a talk given by Andy Strominger entitled Black Holes- The Harmonic Oscillators of the 21st Century. This talk, http://media.physics.harvard.edu/video/?id=COLLOQ_STROMINGER_091310 was quite formidable and has had a lasting impression on my physics studies since. I'd consider the talk transformative in my approach. Now, imagine hearing the power of the harmonic oscillator model for the first time before taking an EM or QM class and simply having a spring mass system in mind...

Fast forward a few years and consider learning the eigenfunctions of the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian ${\Omega_n}$ are an orthonormal basis set for $\mathcal{H}=L_2(\mathbb{R^d},d\mu)$. A statement equivalent to:

1) Schwartz Space $\mathscr{S}$ being Fourier invariant

2) The Fourier inversion theorem holding

Now, the power of the harmonic oscillator is coming to fruition in what I can solve in physics. Admittedly, there is still much in the field that is beyond me at this point that is well represented by the harmonic oscillator model.

This leads me to first ask what are the best known fits for the harmonic oscillator model?

However, this question is not the main focus of this post as I am also deeply interested in models extending beyond the harmonic oscillator paradigm. Namely, what are examples of objects currently being modeled as Black holes? It's interesting (for me, hopefully more) to ask this question in the "firewall" era, given that I attended this talk before the now famous AMPS paper.

So, in summary I am asking for examples of physical objects modeled by harmonic oscillators, or black holes, relevant in the field today. It would be interesting to compare the usage of the models in light of the theme of Andy Strominger's talk.

Comment: Black holes are modeled as black holes, does that count? If not, then I'd say no one is modeling something that is *not* a black hole as a black hole (wouldn't make sense to do it really).

Comment: He said he often tells graduate students, who aren't sure what to work on for a thesis to "beat something down, and turn it into a black hole." Thus, I believe the main emphasis is to take the tools we've acquired in studying black holes and extend them to other problems.

Comment: Well if you want some anecdotes, a classmate of mine once remarked to a professor how amazing it was that the harmonic oscillator appeared everywhere. The prof replied, "No, it's not amazing. We do it by design because it's something we can solve."

Comment: @KyleKanos: I wish I could upvote your above comment 4 times.

Comment: A quibble: Point (1) the bijectivity of $\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{S} \to \mathscr{S}$ is not equivalent to (2) the Fourier inversion theorem's holding. We also have the bijectivity of $\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{S}^\prime \to \mathscr{S}^\prime$, where $\mathscr{S}^\prime$ is the space of tempered distributions, the topological dual $\mathscr{S}^\prime\subset \mathscr{S}^*$ of $\mathscr{S}$.

Comment: Also, Prof. Strominger's comment is, I think, a metaphor for "can you describe something seemingly complex and intractable accurately in terms of something known?". In Prof. Strominger's field, something simple and understood is a black hole. Eighty years ago, a "prototypical", known, understood quantum system was an harmonic oscillator, and many deep findings in physics were made by people thinking about complex systems as approximated by a harmonic oscillator. So there's an analogy; I don't believe he means take it literally.

Comment: As for the quibble, you can check out the abstract on this set of notes: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1385011.files/Jaffe-Notes%20on%20Hilbert%20and%20Schwartz%20Space.pdf

Comment: Also, black holes are far from understood. The firewall paradox isn't over...